# Unable to fetch data from db and set to a struts combo box

Tags: jsp, struts2

I'm new to struts I'm finding it difficult to fetch data from the database and setting it in a combo box.

I'm trying to

- Fetch data from the database
- Set it to combo box
- Populate my action class with the value selected in the combo box

**My JSP:**

```
<s:combobox name="news.appn" list="apptnList" value="Select" headerKey="-1" headerValue="--     selectyour Application--"> </s:combobox>
```

News is my pojo Class

My action class has a list, "apptnList " which holds the values being fetched from the database.
My pojo has a variable appn, which is supposed to holds the data from the combo box.

Comment: `<s:combobox name="news.appn" list="apptnList" value="Select" headerKey="-1" headerValue="--select your Application--"> </s:combobox>`

Answer (score 0):

create a apptnList in your action class and call that action class before redirecting to your page.

```
List<String> apptnList; //add getter and setters
String execute()
{
    apptnList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //create Connection and ResultSet 
    while(rs.next())
       apptnList.add(rs.getString("column_name"));

}
```

Comment: yea...i tried , but e1 before the form is submitted the combobox should have have the list rite! ....so instead of execute() i used another method ...e1 though it dint work.
Thanks.